# Why is this Node.js code not logging anything on the console?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb')
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient

const connectionURL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'
const databaseName = 'task-manager'

MongoClient.connect(connectionURL, (error, client) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log('Unable to connect to database.')
    }

    console.log('Connection successful.')
})
```

I'm not getting any errors but still nothing gets printed to the console.

I'm trying to connect to the mongodb server.

Comment: If you're following a tutorial, find a more recent one

Comment: `MongoClient.connect` returns a promise in newer version. The callback is simple not called anymore. (Because the callback is not expected since they switched to promises.)

Comment: I see, I was following an older tutorial. Using async/await fixed the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code snippet:

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb')
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient

const connectionURL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'
const databaseName = 'task-manager'
const collectionName = 'tasks'

const client = new MongoClient(connectionURL);

async function main() {
    client.connect()  
    console.log(client)
}

main()
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error)
    .finally(() => client.close());
```

Also, refer to the get started guide: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/quick-start/connect-to-mongodb/